# Can we use Composition for Custom Exception in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, composition, solid-principles

We are trying hard not to use extends(IS-A Inheritance) project.
But what about Custom Exceptions, where people usually extends from existing Exception classes.
What could be right solution here?

```
class CustomException{

private Exception exception;
....

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception classes must extends the Throwable class (Exception extends Throwable). What you are trying to achieve is not possible in Java.

What you can still do is something like:

```
class CustomException extends Exception {

private Throwable cause;
//...

}
```

This is actually done in standard Java to store the exception that was the root of that exception. And typically you would do:

```
try {
 // ...
} catch(AnotherException e) {
 //...
 throw new CustomException(e);
}
```

Why is this designed like that ?

Well there a set of standard features all exceptions must have in java, you can see in Throwable:

- provide a cause
- provide an error message
- the stacktrace of where the exception was raised in the code.

It could have been done through interfaces, that's true, but the JRE use a class.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way around it. An exception must be a subclass of `Throwable` - as specified in [Java Language Specification 11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1):

> An exception is represented by an instance of the class Throwable (a direct subclass of Object) or one of its subclasses.

Custom exceptions that you create should be subclasses of either `Exception` or of `RuntimeException` (which are subclasses of `Throwable`).